# How to finish OSB closet?

Tags: closet, finish, osb

I have a master bedroom closet that is unfinished OSB.  Is there an easy way to finish it smooth, fill joints and paint without installing wallboard over it?  Will joint compound work in the gaps and corners? Caulk?

Comment: OSB will probably not finish perfectly smooth/flat.  OSB seems to be an odd choice of wall covering.  Being a closet it will depend on how well you want it to look.

Comment: Agree an odd choice - result of remodel by prior owner i suspect

Comment: Is the OSB Cedar?  I have seen Cedar OSB in closets.

Comment: I don’t believe so.  Garden variety OSB the slapped up in the remodel.

Answer (score 3):

Given that **easy way** is actually part of the question, I'm going to make my comment an answer. Trying to mud OSB smooth is NOT easy.

Even 1/4" of drywall over it will be much easier to finish smooth. By avoiding a little work installing drywall you're making a **lot** more work trying to finish it flat & smooth.

And even that thin layer of drywall will have much better performance in a fire situation than bare OSB. [Table 2](https://awc.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/AWC-DCA1-FlameSpreadPerformance-1906.pdf) lists OSB with flame spreads from 75-175 and smoke developed from 60-194, while drywall is [consistently 15](https://www.usg.com/content/dam/USG_Marketing_Communications/united_states/product_promotional_materials/finished_assets/sheetrock-gypsum-panels-regular-submittal-WB1473.pdf) with smoke developed at 0.

Comment: Fair point on which is easier and more effective.  I didn’t appreciate the safety point either.

Answer (score 0):

Hot mud any gaps. Use an oil based primer (cheap) or a shellac based primer (smell goes away faster) to seal the surface of the wood against water. Tape and mud the corners with taping joint compound. Apply a skim coat of taping joint compound, and then optionally apply a coat of topping compound. Sand, prime, and paint.